# How to check if current directory is using SVN?

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
parse_svn_repo(){
    svn info | grep 'Relative URL' | awk '{print $NF}'
}
```

Which returns the current `Relative URL` of a folder if its using SVN. I need for this script to return this URL only if the current folder is using SVN. It currently runs once only.

I have it set like this:

```
PS1="$(parse_svn_repo)"
```

How can I do print this to the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the old methods don't work anymore, so we have to invent new ones.

For a recent enough SVN you have to check the return code of the command.
So the function would be like this:

```
 parse_svn_repo(){
     local url;
     url=$(svn info 2>&1 | grep 'Relative URL');
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo $url | awk '{print $NF}';
     else
         echo "Default Prompt> ";
     fi;
 }
```

Such a prompt looks prettty ugly but I assume that you're going to adjust the prompt for the cases when you're in the repository

Comment: Yes, but I am running this command in the terminal. I need the message to print the `Relative URL` on `PS1`

Comment: That's not true for 1.7+ - there's only one `.svn` in the root.

Comment: @gespinha use this **echo `svn info | awk '/Relative URL:/ {print " ["$3"]"}'`**